# Sitecore 10.1 jss 16 cannot correctly identify renderings in integrated mode

Tags: jss

I have created jss project with react template, and I have added typescript support by installing some typescript libraries and adding to `server.webpack.config.js` next config:

```
module: {
rules: [
{
 test: /.(ts|tsx)?$/,
 exclude: /node_modules/,
 use: {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
  babelrc: false,
  presets: [env, reactApp],
}...
```

and adding additional logic of checking `ts/tsx extensions` to generate-`component-factory.js`.

In connected mode everything is ok, but in integrated mode, after deploying I see desirable rendering but with styles which Sitecore adds if cannot find rendering.

In logs, I see errors like

> Placeholder jss-main contains unknown component Header. Ensure that a
> React component exists for it, and that it is registered in your
> componentFactory.js.

### Screenshots

**Integrated Mode**

[image]

**Connected Mode**

[image]

Using only js instead of ts everything works as expected.
Has anyone come across a similar?